# How to collapse an IEnumerable of an IEnumerable to a single IEnumerable?

Tags: delphi, ienumerable, delphi-xe7, spring4d

```
function TSomething.Concat<T>(const E: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>): IEnumerable<T>;
begin
  Result := TConcatIterator<T>.Create(E) as IEnumerable<T>;
end;
```

That doesn't compile, because `TConcatIterator<T>` can only concat two enumerables, but what I need is an iterator that concats an enumerable of enumerables.

Haskell has the `concat` function that does this:

```
concat [[1, 2, 3], [4,5]] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The Delphi version would look like this:

```
class function TForm1.Concat<T>(
  const AEnumerable: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>): IEnumerable<T>;
begin
  // ???
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  InnerList1: IList<Integer>;
  InnerList2: IList<Integer>;
  OuterList: IList<IEnumerable<Integer>>;
  Concated: IEnumerable<Integer>;
begin
  InnerList1 := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>([1, 2, 3]);
  InnerList2 := TCollections.CreateList<Integer>([4, 5]);
  OuterList := TCollections.CreateList<IEnumerable<Integer>>([InnerList1, InnerList2]);
  Concated := Concat<Integer>(OuterList);
end;
```

How can I implement this in spring4d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Spring4D collections are modelled after those in .Net the operation/method you are looking for is called [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

In 1.2 we have a static method for that in the `TEnumerable` type so the code would look like that:

```
Concated := TEnumerable.SelectMany<IEnumerable<Integer>, Integer>(OuterList,
  function(x: IEnumerable<Integer>): IEnumerable<Integer>
  begin
    Result := x;
  end);
```

However this is a bit verbose so you can easily write a method to handle the special case of flattening an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to an `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
type
  TEnumerableHelper = class helper for TEnumerable
    class function SelectMany<T>(const source: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>): IEnumerable<T>; overload; static;
  end;

class function TEnumerableHelper.SelectMany<T>(
  const source: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>): IEnumerable<T>;
begin
  Result := TSelectManyIterator<IEnumerable<T>, T>.Create(source,
    function(x: IEnumerable<T>): IEnumerable<T>
    begin
      Result := x;
    end);
end;
```

and use this just easily like this:

```
Concated := TEnumerable.SelectMany<Integer>(OuterList);
```

The SelectMany operation is deferred executed and lazy evaluated.

Comment: I just discovered that in Haskell `SelectMany` corresponds to `concatMap`  or `=<<` (bind) (in the [] monad), that's really cool.

Answer (score 1):

A strict (= non lazy) version might look like this:

```
class function TForm1.Concat<T>(
  const AEnumerable: IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>): IEnumerable<T>;
var
  L: IList<T>;
begin
  L := TCollections.CreateList<T>;
  AEnumerable.ForEach(
    procedure(const AInnerEnum: IEnumerable<T>)
    begin
      L.AddRange(AInnerEnum);
    end);
  Result := L as IEnumerable<T>;
end;
```